# Conditional Insert or Update in Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, stored-procedures, insert

I have one table in oracle where data gets inserted from some third party. I want to populate master tables from that table.  So, what will be the best way performance wise using collection.

E.g. Suppose, the table into which data will get populated from third party is 'EMP_TMP'.

Now I want to populate 'EMPLOYEE' master table through procedure which will get populated from EMP_TMP Table.

Here again there is one condition like IF SAME EMPID (this is not primary key) EXISTS then we have to UPDATE FULL TABLE which consists of SAME EMPID ELSE we have INSERT NEW RECORD.

[Note: Here EMPID is VARCHAR2 and EMPNO will be primary key where we will use SEQUENCE]

I think here merge will not perform much better performancewise since we cant use collection in MERGE statement.

Comment: You need to explain a bit better about why Merge would not work. It's designed for this upsert style scenario. The alternative is to go back to old school pre-merge which was 2 statements, an inner join for the updates and a left anti join for the inserts.

Comment: I know Merge will work.  It will be ok for me if it will give performance better than BULK COLLECT. Here data will also be in lakhs.

Comment: @user1017936 - A single SQL statement (whether `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `MERGE`) will be more efficient than writing looping code that simulates that same operation.  Using `BULK COLLECT` makes looping code more efficient but it won't make it more efficient than SQL.

Comment: Even at a few hundred k rows, this is a small data set - the performance between the two should not represent a large difference. Unless you can already show a performance issue, you are premturely optimizing - do what is maintainable and adhering to your standards - dragging an extra second or two performance out of a small ETL like this is unlikely to warrent the effort.

Comment: I dont have any restriction to use SQL only.  I can use procedure also, it would be much better if someone can show me the script based on BULK COLLECT.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if performance is your primary consideration, and you don't like MERGE, then how about this (run as script, single transaction):

```
delete from EMPLOYEE where emp_id IN (
select emp_id from EMP_TMP);

insert into EMPLOYEE
select * from EMP_TMP;

commit;
```

Obviously not the "safest" approach (and as written assumes exact same table definitions and you have the rollback), but should be fast (you could also mess with IN vs EXISTS etc).  And I couldn't quite understand your post if emp_id or emp_no was the common key in these 2 tables, but use whichever makes sense in your situation.

Comment: I cant use delete since here emp_id is primary key generated by sequence it will later on have child record also. For reference empid will be like 1,2 and emp_no will be VARCHAR2 like 'ABC','DEF'

Comment: @user1017936 - what you have said in that comment is *the exact opposite* of what you said in your question.  Please make your mind up.  Anyway it doesn't matter what teh actiual key is, providing you have one.  Deleting a record in the target table where some key matches the key in the source table and then inserting the temp record into the target table is exactly the same as doing "UPDATE FULL TABLE"

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure, you need to be using PL/SQL.
Do an update first then test sql%rowcount.
If it is 0, no updates where done and you have to do an insert instead.

I think that this is fairly efficient.

pseudo code

```
Update table;
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
   //get new sequence number
   insert into table;
END IF;
COMMIT;
```

HTH 
Harv

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the solution.  Can you guys just clarify one last thing.  Now, which update will run more FASTER.  Whether it will be through MERGE or USING PSEUDOCODE ???????

Comment: I am pretty sure that MERGE will run faster, but I cannot say this definitively.

Comment: How often does this have to run? How many records will be processed each time it runs?

Comment: This will run in nightly scheduled job.  Number of records will not be too large since here data is for Master Tables